# SetFocus() fails with a valid window handle

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a program with several custom controls. One of these custom controls is a text input control. Since a window does not automatically receive keyboard focus when you click on it, i've created a mouse hook in my program that calls SetFocus() on a window when the user clicks in that window. However, there is a problem.

If another program has focus when you click on my program's window (or any of the controls in that window) SetFocus() fails. I then have to click again for it to succeed. Here's the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK kbfProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) // Keyboard focus switching procedure
{
    switch(nCode)
    {
        case HC_ACTION:
        {
            if(wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * mhs = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;

                if(SetFocus(mhs->hwnd) == NULL)
                {
                    printf("SetFocus(Hwnd = %.8x) failed. Error code: %lu\n", mhs->hwnd, GetLastError());
                } else {

                    printf("SetFocus(Hwnd = %.8x) returned success.\n", mhs->hwnd);
                }
            }

        }
        break;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And the output of those printf calls is this:

```
SetFocus(Hwnd = 00410c06) failed. Error code: 87
SetFocus(Hwnd = 00410c06) returned success.
SetFocus(Hwnd = 01740fc8) failed. Error code: 87
SetFocus(Hwnd = 01740fc8) returned success.
```

Error code 87 is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, but i'm obviously passing a valid window handle to the function, so why is it failing?

Comment: Your kbfProc callback method is assumingly called whenever the mouse moves? Show us the call to the WINAPI method.

Also, I think it's preferable to set the focus via a form load event.

Comment: @opatachibueze WINAPI method? Form load event? Isn't that from .NET? I'm using C++...

Comment: What part of your code is using LRESULT CALLBACK kbfProc

Comment: I'm confused about the need for the mouse hook.  Are all the windows above your text input window marked with WS_EX_TRANSPARENT?  If so, clicking the mouse in the text input window should set focus to the window.

Comment: @opatachibueze the kbfProc is the hook procedure. It's called by windows. The code that sets the hook is this: `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, kbfProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId())`

Comment: @LarryOsterman No, none of my custom controls have any extended styles applied to them. However, simply clicking on a (custom) control will not set the keyboard focus.

Comment: How "custom" is your custom control?  If, for instance the text input field subclasses a text box, it should work fine.  You can dramatically change the visuals while still keeping the core input functionality.  In general, it's often better to find a window control that's close in function to the one you want to emulate and subclass it than to completely roll your own.

Comment: Btw, the reason you're having difficulties with your SetFocus call is that Windows tries very hard to prevent apps from stealing focus.  My guess is that the calls which are failing are failing because Windows thinks you're trying to steal focus from the current input window - opatachibueze's solution below will help there.   But I'm STILL leery about the need for an input hook - I know they're needed in some circumstances, but this doesn't seem like one of them.

Comment: @LarryOsterman The control is completely custom. Custom window class, custom window procedure. The text input control doubles as a dropdown list with a scrollbar - all with custom graphics. So, i felt the need to create a custom control in this case. Also, i understand why you are skeptical about the need of an input hook - i could just handle the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message in each control's window procedure and call SetFocus there, but it seems better to have the code for setting the keyboard focus all in one place. The hook is local only - it doesn't track mouse input in other programs.

Comment: Larry is right. The problem is that your control is missing functionality. You should fix the control. An input hook is entirely inappropriate here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What functionality is my control missing? Without the keyboard focus, it won't receive keystrokes. When i simply click on the control, keyboard focus isn't switched to the control, i have to explicitly call SetFocus(). I tried commenting out the hook and moving the SetFocus() call into the controls window procedure's WM_LBUTTONDOWN handler, but i still have the same problem when i do that.

Comment: @Gogeta70: The custom graphics can be easily handled with a custom paint handler, that doesn't need anything special.  You'd be surprised at how much you can style standard controls.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure what is missing, you might want to use SPY++ and see what messages are sent to a stock text control and what are sent to your control - there's probably a message you're not handling properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. After a lot of googling and trial & error I eventually came across [this](http://chabster.blogspot.com/2010/03/focus-and-window-activation-in-win32.html) webpage ([backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120501233208/http://chabster.blogspot.com/2010/03/focus-and-window-activation-in-win32.html)). It goes over the behavior of window focus and activation in detail.

I ended up adding some code to the WM_ACTIVATE handler of my main window that searches for the child window that was clicked when the window is activated. Here's all the code:

Here's the hook procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK kbfProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(nCode)
    {
        case HC_ACTION:
        {
            if(wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * mhs = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;
                
                BringWindowToTop(MainWindow->t_hwnd);
                SetFocus(mhs->hwnd);
            }
            
        }
        break;
    }
    
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Here's the code i put in the WM_ACTIVATE handler:

```
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
    {
        unsigned long state = (unsigned long) wParam & 0x0000FFFF;
        unsigned long mState = (unsigned long) wParam & 0xFFFF0000;
        
        if(state != 0)
        {
            ...[some code here]...
            
            FocusChildWindow(hwnd);
        }
        
        ...[some code here]...
    }
    break;
```

And here's the FocusChildWindow() function:

```
void FocusChildWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    POINT mpos;
    GetCursorPos(&mpos);
    
    RECT wr;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &wr);
    
    mpos.x -= wr.left;
    mpos.y -= wr.top;
    
    HWND cw = ChildWindowFromPoint(hwnd, mpos);
    
    if(cw == NULL || cw == hwnd)
    {
        SetFocus(hwnd);
    } else {
        
        GetCursorPos(&mpos);
        HWND cw2;
        
        while(1)
        {
            POINT sc = mpos;
            MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, cw, &sc, 1);
            
            cw2 = ChildWindowFromPoint(cw, sc);
            
            if(cw2 == NULL || cw2 == cw)
            {
                SetFocus(cw);
                break;
            } else {
                
                cw = cw2;
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you're calling SetFocus, the window must be attached to the calling thread's message queue or SetFocus will return invalid if it's not. To workaround this, use [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first when the mouse moves over your window before calling `SetFocus`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but i'm still getting the exact same result.

Comment: Hmm, what is the return value of SetFocus when it succeeds in the two cases? It should return the window that had the previous focus. Also, have you tried `SetActiveWindow` ?

Comment: Have you tried `AttachThreadInput(GetWindowThreadProcessId(window), GetCurrentThreadId(), true)`?

Comment: @Gogeta70 Try Jonathan Lingle's suggestion and tell us the result. NB: Perform that instead of `SetForeGroundWindow` before using SetFocus.

Comment: @JonathanLingle Properly attaching and detaching from threads of an external process would be a real mess, i imagine. I've just figured out the solution to my problem, i'll post an answer now. Still, thank you to everyone for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm couple of days late, but since I just spent a whole day trying to fix this, I'll add my fix here as well, just in case it helps someone.

Basically it was the AttachThreadInput thing mentioned above in a comment. GetActiveWindow() was always returning NULL as well. Which window you need to attach to might vary case by case, but I needed the root window, so I used GetAncestor. If you know the window handle you want, then you can just use it instead. So this is the code that fixed it for me:

```
AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_ROOT), NULL), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me when SetFocus() had no effect setting the keyboard focus to a child control window on a property sheet page window:

`::SendMessage(m_hPropPageWnd, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, MAKEWPARAM(UIS_CLEAR, UISF_HIDEFOCUS), 0);`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I gotta say though, you are about 8 years too late... :P